# Accents in URL, how can I escape them correctly ?

Tags: javascript, url, character-encoding, diacritics, fragment-identifier

I have to get what is next to the # character in the URL (in javascript). When there's an é, for example, I get escaped characters. I can unescape() them, but I get weird characters such as Ã. How can I get the right characters ?

Comment: An example would be great for us to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) and [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp). [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) and [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) will be useful only for ASCII charset, while the former supports unicode charsets.

Comment: [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is much better JavaScript reference than w3schools.

Comment: Lol'd! I use w3schools for references links while posting solutions here in SO.